# How to fetch url dynamically

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I made wordpress website with pods custom field url. I designed Project post type template with elementor pro and fetch fields data from custom fields. Now I trying to make after filling form it goest to thank you page with project id and url. On thank you page every projects have different brochure so I called brochure from project. But after added second project the brochure still showing previous projects.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.